# Escaping $ in shell script performing operations on oracle using pl-sql

Tags: shell, plsql

According to internet `$` is escaped using a single `\` in shell.

But this does not work:

```
testvar=\`sqlplus -s / as sysdba<< EOF
select name from v\$datafile;
EOF\`

echo $testvar
```

Escaping by `\\\` only work:

```
testvar=\`sqlplus -s / as sysdba<< EOF
```

select name from v\$datafile;
EOF`

```
echo $testvar
```

Can someone explain this please, I am very confused.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
testvar=$(sqlplus -s / as sysdba<< EOF
select name from v\$datafile;
EOF
)

echo $testvar
```